# TypeORM NestJS migration form 0.2 to 0.3 multi tenant schema

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

I want to upgrade typeorm to version 3 but I am left with the problem of linking to the correct schema, my file looks like this:

```
import {
    Connection,
    createConnection,
    getConnectionManager,
} from 'typeorm';
import { PostgresConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresConnectionOptions';

import * as tenantsOrmconfig from '../../tenants-orm.config';

export function getTenantConnection(tenantId: string): Promise<Connection> {
    const connectionName = `tenant_${tenantId}`;
    const connectionManager = getConnectionManager();

    if (connectionManager.has(connectionName)) {
        const connection = connectionManager.get(connectionName);
        return Promise.resolve(connection.isConnected ? connection : connection.connect());
    }

    return createConnection({
        ...(tenantsOrmconfig as PostgresConnectionOptions),
        name: connectionName,
        schema: connectionName,
    });
}
```

I have to replace `getConnectionManager`,  do You have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can walk around [my repo](https://github.com/HaiAlison/boiler-plate-nestjs/tree/concurrent-insert),
i've a function like this to create connection:

```js
async createConnection(name: string) {
    const config = await this.getDatabaseConfig(name); //this is just get config by name in my db
    if (!config) {
      throw new BadRequestException('DATABASE NOT FOUND');
    }
    config.password = this.decryptPassword(config.password);
    const configs = {
      ...config,
      entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.{ts,js}'],
      migrations: ['dist/migrations/*.{ts,js}'],
      migrationsRun: true,
      migrationsTableName: 'typeorm_migrations',
      synchronize: false,
      ssl: false,
      logging: true,
    } as DataSourceOptions;
    const connection = new DataSource(configs);
    if (!connection.isInitialized) await connection.initialize();
    console.log('isInitialized', connection.isInitialized);
    return connection;
  }
```

and use like this:

```js
const connection: DataSource = await this.dynamicDbService.createConnection(
  name,
);
```